# SQL Server Group By Last 24 Hours, Last 7 Days and Last 14 Days

Tags: sql, pivot

I need to write an SQL query to produce the following result set. What's the best way to achieve this?

```
Time Range          Qty                Amount
===============================================
Last 24 Hours       56                 $2000
Last 7 Days         359                $3900
Last 14 Days        2321               $22,888
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 4):

```
select  'Last 24 hours'
,       sum(Qty) as Qty
,       sum(Amount) as Amount
from    YourTable
where   TradeDt > dateadd(hour, -24, getdate())
union all
select  'Last 7 days'
,       sum(Qty)
,       sum(Amount)
from    YourTable
where   TradeDt > dateadd(day, -7, getdate())
union all
select  'Last 14 days'
,       sum(Qty)
,       sum(Amount)
from    YourTable
where   TradeDt > dateadd(day, -14, getdate())
```

Comment: Thanks Andomar. That's way I can think of too. Just wondering if there is a smarter way to pivot the data?

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be to use UNION, if you absolutely need a table as a result (otherwise, you could just fetch the data row by row).

I don't think that there is any nicer way to do this in SQL.

```
SELECT 'Last 24 hours', SUM(qty), SUM(amount)
 FROM table
 WHERE datediff(day, getdate(), date) = 1

UNION

SELECT 'Last 7 days', SUM(qty), SUM(amount)
 FROM table
 WHERE datediff(getdate(), date, 'day') < 7

UNION

SELECT 'Last 14 days', SUM(qty), SUM(amount)
 FROM table
 WHERE datediff(getdate(), date, 'day') < 14
```

Comment: It's often better to do `dateadd` on a constant like `14` than on a column.  This allows SQL Server to use an index on `Date` if there is one.  +1

Answer (score 0):

you can use a where clause on dateAdd like

```
select * from table
where datefield > DateAdd(d,-1,getdate())
```

select * from table
    where datefield > DateAdd(d,-7,getdate())
select * from table
    where datefield > DateAdd(d,-14,getdate())

for day and so on

Comment: select * from table where datefield > DateAdd(d,-1,getdate())